# How to refresh UI after performing new get method using Room and LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I'm writing android application using JetPack architecture (i'm also using Sunflower application as an inspiration).

I have recycler view with list of tasks. To get them i'm using below function in view model. And initial load is working properly.

However I have also Date Picker where i want to update finishedDate to new date to get finished tasks from other day.

Updating finishedDate variable or invoking another getTasksByFinishedDate function to reassign tasks (after changing scope from val to var) brings no effect. I'm still displaying only initial tasks.

Observe functionality is working properly for this field (LiveData<List>) because if I add new tasks with the finished date that is currently displaying i will see it on UI.

I just can't filter them to different date after initial call.

Codes are below:

ViewModel:

```
fun updateDate(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
    finishedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
    finishedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
    finishedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day) 
    // tasks: LiveData<List<Task>> = taskRepository.getTasksByFinishedDate(finishedDate)
    }

val tasks: LiveData<List<Task>> = taskRepository.getTasksByFinishedDate(finishedDate)
```

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE finishedDate = :finishedDate")
fun getTasksByFinishedDate(finishedDate: Calendar): LiveData<List<Task>>
```

Fragment subscribe to UI:

```
ViewModel.tasks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
   adapter.submitList(result)
}
```

DatePicker:

```
    private val model: NewTaskViewModel by activityViewModels()
    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        this.year = year
        this.month = month
        this.day = day

        model.updateDate(year, month, day)
    }
```

Comment: Are you updating field in ROOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is called `MediatorLiveData`.

The idea is, that you can keep a final LiveData object in your ViewModel and only adjust the `source` of the Mediator:

In your Repo:

```
private MediatorLiveData<List<Tasks>> mObservableTasks;
private LiveData<List<SeedEntity>> tasks;

private DataRepository(...) {
    ...
    tasks = mDatabase.myDao().getTasksByFinishedDate(defaultDate);
    mObservableTasks = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    mObservableTasks.addSource(tasks,
            taskLists-> {
                if (mDatabase.getDatabaseCreated().getValue() != null) {
                    mObservableTasks.postValue(taskLists);
                }
            });
}

public void updateDate(Calendar finishedDate)
{
        mObservableTasks.removeSource(tasks);
        tasks = mDatabase.myDao().getTasksByFinishedDate(finishedDate);
        mObservableTasks.addSource(tasks,
                taskLists-> {
                    if (mDatabase.getDatabaseCreated().getValue() != null)
                        mObservableTasks.postValue(taskLists);
                });

public LiveData<List<Tasks>> getObservableTasks(){
    return mObservableTasks;
}
```

In your ViewModel:

```
final LiveData<..> mObservableTasks = repo.getObservableTasks();
public LiveData<..> getObservableTasks(){
    return mObservableTasks;
}
```

In your View:

```
ViewModel.mObservableTasks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
    adapter.submitList(result)
}
```

Hope this makes it clear ;)